# Html.ActionLink doesn't render # properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When using Html.ActionLink passing a string containing the # char renders it like it is but if you UrlEncode it renders as %2523.

I believe it's a bug. MVC Beta Release.

Is it really a bug?

http://example.com/test# is rendered as

http://example.com/test%2523 instead of

http://example.com/test%2523

Comment: happens to me as well...

Comment: Could you be more detailed? It looks like your expected and result are the same string. What are the parameters you're calling ActionLink with?

Comment: ActionLink does not (and should not) UrlEncode what you pass to it. UrlEncoding is used to encode the value on a query string so that it doesn't conflict with the &name=value format.

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug :) You don't want to UrlEncode actual urls - UrlEncode helps you encode text *within* urls that might conflict with the URI control characters. In the same way, you wouldn't pass actual HTML into HtmlEncode unless you wanted to show your users the HTML itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, run the following Console application and see what it outputs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hash = "#";
            Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hash));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the problem... I'm using MVC, and the Html.ActionLink outputs # if I don't use UrlEncode, but if I do, it outputs %2523 which is %23 encoded....

maybe it's a bug?

thanks!

Comment: Glad you found the problem - could you please edit your question to make it match the problem more, something like "URL encoding with MVC", would be nice to have the issue documented so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Is HttpUtility.UrlEncode the same as Server.UrlEncode?  (HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode)

I cannot do a check right now, not near a .NET machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in # as part of parameters of ActionLink? If so, you should just append it like this: Html.ActionLink("test") + "#"